# How to split a single column into two based on where clause

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone suggest me how to split a single column into two? Here's my table named ax_cash_book.

[image: Please find the image of the table below]

I want to split the amount column into two columns named "Credit" where trans_type ='Credit' and "Debit" where trans_type = 'Debit'. I tried to write a query like this :

```
select amount as Credit, amount as Debit from ax_cash_book
```

But I am unable to find the appropriate place for including the where clause. Please suggest me some query to sort out the problem.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I suspect you want to use two case statements - e.g. select case when trans_type = 'Credit' then amount else 0 end as Credit, and similarly for debit. Assuming you do not want a where clause as you want to apply this to every row, and a where clause is only needed to filter out rows

Comment: please post your attempt to use CASE, and the results it gave you. Please add that detail to the question rather than hiding in a comment.

Comment: @mc110 Thank you so much.. case statement worked well for me.. :)

Comment: `select case when trans_type = 'Credit' then amount else 0 end as Credit, case when trans_type = 'Debit' then amount else 0 end as Debit from ax_cash_book`

Comment: This is something I love about stackoverflow. Instant answers and Correct answers.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the CASE ... WHEN statement for this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN trans_type = 'Credit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS Credit,
    CASE WHEN trans_type = 'Debit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS Debit
FROM ax_cash_book
```

What this will do is when the trans_type column equals "Credit", then use the amount database field.

I take it that if the value is a credit then there is no debit, hence `ELSE 0`.

The same will apply for the Debit field.

Comment: This is not a solution and does not work for me

Comment: but how can we have the complete table with new columns in the end ? since with this query we would have just two columns (credit and debit)

Comment: You would add the remaining columns before or after the CASE WHEN statements, after SELECT and before the FROM line, comma separated. You would need to lookup what those column names were though from the table you are querying. You could add * to add these lazily but it would also add the original trans_type column in the above example.

So, something like:
`SELECT column1, column2, CASE WHEN column3 = 'some_value' THEN 'something' ELSE 'something_else' END AS column3name, column4, column5 FROM  table_name`